# Middleware Auth in Lumen [ Class 'Auth' not found ]

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware, lumen

I'm using Lumen 5.2 (by Laravel)

I'm getting this wrong:
**Fatal error: Class 'Auth' not found in C:\wamp64\www\project\app\Http\Middleware\AuthToken.php on line 10**

**bootstrap/app.php**

```
$app->routeMiddleware([
   'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\AuthToken::class,
]);
```

**Middleware/AuthToken.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Auth;

class AuthToken
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
            return $next($request);
        }else{
            abort(401);
        }
    }
}
```

**UserController.php**

use Auth;

```
public function login(Request $request){
    if ($request->has('password')) {
        $user = User:: where("user_password", "=", $request->input('password'))->first();
        if ($user) {
            $token=str_random(60);
            $user->api_token=$token;
            $user->save();

            return redirect('admin/dashboard');
        }
}
```

**routes.php**

```
/* ADMIN */

$app->get('/admin', function () use ($app) {
    return $app->make('view')->make('admin.login');
});

$app->group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () use ($app){

    $app->get('dashboard', function () use ($app) {
        return $app->make('view')->make('admin.dashboard');
    });

});
```

how can i login whats the problem?

edit: i've tried

```
$app->routeMiddleware([
    'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
]);
```

I am getting just  **Unauthorized.**

Answer (score 1):

In `Middleware/AuthToken.php` import the `Auth` class like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

What you want here is to use the `Auth Facade`, so you need to import it.

Comment: Should i enabled $app->withFacades(); in app.php ?

Comment: I did enable and I'm getting HttpException in RegistersExceptionHandlers.php line 32:

Comment: Yes, you should enable.

Comment: Maybe you don't have a logged user?

Comment: I have an user already direct to admin/dashboard but how i enable the session

Comment: To log in an user you can do `Auth::login($user)`, where $user is an instance from the `Authenticable` user.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthToken
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
            return $next($request);
        }else{
            abort(401); //works here
        }
    }
}
```

[image: error]